Bash - Log timestamp of the moment data was received on stdin, coming from a pipe
I have an application that outputs to stdout from time to time - random intervals, random durations of outputting before going silent again. Its output (binary data) is captured into a file.
I want to be able to log a timestamp of the moment when the output started, but only if the application kept outputting for at least 3 seconds, and also log the time when the output has stopped if no output was received for at least 5 seconds after the stop (if it is received, consider it part of the previous period).
Start: (date +'%d.%m - %H:%M:%S')
End: (date +'%d.%m - %H:%M:%S')

The output must be transparently redirected to the file after that.
Something like tee, but with timestamp logger, say:
app | monitor > out
monitor could output either to a log file or stderr, doesn't matter.
Is there a way to do this with common tools available on the shell?
I could write a Python script, but i don't wanna overcomplicate the task for no reason.

If it's binary data you should use python

One of the reasons listed to close a question on this forum is "Needs debugging details" which would apply in this case as there's no code and no [mcve], plus asking for tool suggestions rather than asking for help with your code is another of the specific reasons listed to close a question.

You can program monitor in pretty any language you want - Python, Lisp, bash, awk, ... you name it. However, you can only log the time when the data arrives at monitor, which is not necessarily the same as when app writes it. You could consider making app write to stdout unbuffered, in order to get more accurate times. BTW, I don't quite see in which respect an implementation in Python would be significantly more complicate than one in bash.

I've written something a while back when I wanted to log the data going through a pipe for a histogram. It's a pretty quick an dirty C program but It-work-for-me (tm). You can just put it somewhere in your pipe and the data going through it just passed along unaltered. JSON is outputted to stderror, or to a file with the -o switch.
Here's an example:
{ echo -n A; sleep 3; echo -n B; sleep 6; echo -n C; } | ./pipe_histo2 -z 2>&1 >/dev/null | jq .


{
  "measurements": [
     [ 0, 1 ],
     [ 2, 1 ],
     [ 8, 1 ]
  ],
  "min": 0,
  "max": 1,
  "avg": 0.333336,
  "total": 3,
  "start_time": "2024-06-28 23:31:34.338997847",
  "start_epoch": "1719610294",
  "end_time": "2024-06-28 23:31:43.338917382",
  "end_epoch": "1719610303",
  "elapsed": 8,
  "total_readable": "3B",
  "elapsed_readable": "08s"
}

Here's the C code. Copy this into a file called pipe_histo2.c
/*

To compile: gcc -Wall -o pipe_histo2 pipe_histo2.c

Examples:

{ echo -n A; sleep 3; echo -n B; sleep 3; echo -n C; } | ./pipe_histo 2>&1 >/dev/null | jq .
ls -als /dev | ./pipe_histo2

*/



/***************************************************************************/
/** Includes                                                              **/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>         // atexit

#include <sys/time.h>       // select
#include <sys/types.h>      // select
#include <unistd.h>         // select

#include <time.h>           // clock_gettime

#include <string.h>         // strlen

char *output_file = NULL;
FILE *output_fd;

unsigned int omit_zero_measurements = 0;
unsigned int omit_seconds = 0;
unsigned int only_output_json = 0;
unsigned int print_graph = 0;


void die(char *S)
{
printf("%s\n", S);
exit(1);
}


void Usage(char *Argv0)
{
printf("\n"
       "Usage:     <some process> | %s [options] [| <some process>]\n"
       "\n"
       " -o <output file>    Output JSON to a file\n"
       " -z                  Omit zero measurements. If value == 0, do not print\n"
       " -s                  Omit seconds. Only print values in the JSON\n"
       " -j                  Only print JSON. Does not output what has been read, only prints JSON\n"
       " -g                  Output an ASCII art graph\n"
       " -h                  This help text\n"
       "\n"
       "Example:   { echo -n A; sleep 3; echo -n B; sleep 6; echo -n C; } | %s -z 2>&1 >/dev/null | jq .\n"
       "\n"
       "           stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 find / -xdev | %s -o result.json | wc -l\n"
       "\n"
       ,Argv0
       ,Argv0
       ,Argv0
       );
exit(0);
}


void parse_arg(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int c;

while((c = getopt(argc, argv, "ho:zsjg")) != -1)
  switch(c)
      {
      case 'o':    output_file = optarg;
                   break;
      case 'z':    omit_zero_measurements = 1;
                   break;
      case 's':    omit_seconds = 1;
                   break;
      case 'j':    only_output_json = 1;
                   break;
      case 'g':    print_graph = 1;
                   break;
      case 'h':    Usage(argv[0]);
                   break;
      case '?':    die("getopt: unknown option");
      default:     die("getopt: default reached. Internal error");
      }

output_fd = stderr;

if(only_output_json)
  output_fd = stdout;

if(output_file)
  if((output_fd = fopen(output_file, "w")) == NULL)
    die("fopen");
}

static void timespec_diff(struct timespec *end, struct timespec *start, struct timespec *result)
{
if(end->tv_nsec < start->tv_nsec)
  {
  result->tv_sec  = end->tv_sec - start->tv_sec - 1;
  result->tv_nsec = 1000000000 + end->tv_nsec - start->tv_nsec;
  }
  else
  {
  result->tv_sec  = end->tv_sec  - start->tv_sec;
  result->tv_nsec = end->tv_nsec - start->tv_nsec;
  }
}



// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304259/formatting-struct-timespec/14746954

static char *timespec2str(struct timespec *TS)
{
static char   ret[] = "2012-12-31 12:59:59.123456789";   // Maximum size
struct tm     t;

tzset();
if(localtime_r(&(TS->tv_sec), &t) == NULL)
  die("localtime_r");

if(strftime(ret, strlen(ret), "%F %T", &t) == 0)
  die("strftime");

sprintf(&ret[strlen(ret)], ".%09ld", TS->tv_nsec);

return ret;
}


double timespec2double(struct timespec *TS)
{
double ret = TS->tv_nsec;

while(ret > 1)
  ret = ret / 10;

return ret + TS->tv_sec;
}



char *printReadableSize(size_t Size)
{
unsigned long long int scale = 1;
char *postfix = "BKMGTPEZY";
static char result[16];

for(; Size / (scale * 1024); scale = scale * 1024, postfix++);

if(Size % scale)
  sprintf(result, "%.02f%.1s", (float) Size / scale, postfix);
  else
  sprintf(result, "%u%.1s", (unsigned int) (Size / scale), postfix);

return result;
}



char *printReadableTime(unsigned long int Seconds)
{
static char       ret[22];
unsigned int      ret_len = 0;

if(Seconds > 31536000) // years
  {
  ret_len = ret_len + sprintf(&ret[ret_len], "%luy", Seconds / 31536000);
  Seconds = Seconds % 31536000;
  }

if(Seconds > 604800) // weeks
  {
  ret_len = ret_len + sprintf(&ret[ret_len], "%luw", Seconds / 604800);
  Seconds = Seconds % 604800;
  }

if(Seconds > 86400) // days
  {
  ret_len = ret_len + sprintf(&ret[ret_len], "%lud", Seconds / 86400);
  Seconds = Seconds % 86400;
  }

if(Seconds > 3600) // hours
  {
  ret_len = ret_len + sprintf(&ret[ret_len], "%luh", Seconds / 3600);
  Seconds = Seconds % 3600;
  }

if(Seconds > 60) // minutes
  {
  ret_len = ret_len + sprintf(&ret[ret_len], "%lum", Seconds / 60);
  Seconds = Seconds % 60;
  }

ret_len = ret_len + sprintf(&ret[ret_len], "%02lus", Seconds);

ret[ret_len] = '\0';
return ret;
}




int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char             buf[4096];
unsigned int     buf_len=0;

fd_set               read_set;
fd_set               error_set;
unsigned long int    t;

struct timespec   start;
struct timespec   end;
struct timespec   tmp;


size_t histo[604800] = { 0 };   // A weeks worth of seconds
unsigned long int histo_len = 0;

size_t value_min;
size_t value_max;
size_t value_total;

unsigned int first = 1;


parse_arg(argc, argv);



FD_ZERO(&read_set);
FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &read_set);
FD_ZERO(&error_set);
FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &error_set);


if(clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start) == -1)
  die("CLOCK_REALTIME");

while(1)
  {
  t = select(STDIN_FILENO+1, &read_set, NULL, &error_set, NULL);

  if(FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &error_set))
    die("error_set\n");

  switch(t)
    {
    case -1:  die("Getch_timeout: select returned -1\n");

    case  0:  die("0 - on blocking call\n");

    default:  buf_len = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, 4096);
              switch(buf_len)
                {
                case -1:   die("read");
                case  0:   goto exit_copy;          // EOF
                }

              if(clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end) == -1)
                die("CLOCK_REALTIME");
              timespec_diff(&end, &start, &tmp);
              histo[tmp.tv_sec] += buf_len;
              histo_len = tmp.tv_sec;

              if(!only_output_json)
                {
                t = write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, buf_len);
                if(t != buf_len)
                  die("write != read\n");
                }
              break;

    } // switch
  } // while

exit_copy:


if(clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end) == -1)
  die("CLOCK_REALTIME");

// Display results

fprintf(output_fd, "{\"measurements\":[");

value_min = histo[0];
value_max = 0;
value_total = 0;

for(t=0; t <= histo_len; t++)
  {
  if(!omit_zero_measurements || histo[t])
    {
    if(first)
      first = 0;
      else
      fprintf(output_fd, ",");
    if(omit_seconds)
      fprintf(output_fd, "%lu", histo[t]);
      else
      fprintf(output_fd, "[%lu,%lu]", t, histo[t]);
    }
  if(histo[t] < value_min)
    value_min = histo[t];
  if(histo[t] > value_max)
    value_max = histo[t];
  value_total += histo[t];
  }


timespec_diff(&end, &start, &tmp);

fprintf(output_fd, "],\"min\":%lu,\"max\":%lu,\"avg\":%f,\"total\":%lu", value_min, value_max, (double) value_total / timespec2double(&tmp), value_total);
fprintf(output_fd, ",\"start_time\":\"%s\",\"start_epoch\":\"%lu\"", timespec2str(&start), start.tv_sec);
fprintf(output_fd, ",\"end_time\":\"%s\",\"end_epoch\":\"%lu\"", timespec2str(&end), end.tv_sec);
fprintf(output_fd, ",\"elapsed\":%lu", tmp.tv_sec);
fprintf(output_fd, ",\"total_readable\":\"%s\",\"elapsed_readable\":\"%s\"", printReadableSize(value_total), printReadableTime(tmp.tv_sec));

if(print_graph)
  {
  fprintf(output_fd, ",\"graph\":\"xx TODO xx\"");
  }

fprintf(output_fd, "}\n");

fclose(output_fd);
return 0;
}

// EOF

